# Target.Address Circular reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set-up an input sheet where the user can enter either rent per square foot or annual rent and when one is entered, the other is solved for. Below is the macro I have created. It is not working (and I understand why it isn't) because it is causing a circular reference.  I also tried this with two separate if statements (without the OR) rather than nested if/OR and if then else. So, basically, if one target address is triggered, I don't want the macro to run on the other (and create the circular reference).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("Current_Rent").Address Or Target.Address = Range("CurrentRentperSqFt").Address Then
        If Target.Address = Range("Current_Rent").Address Then
            Range("CurrentRentperSqFt").Value = "=IF(ISERROR(Current_Rent/SqFt),"""",Current_Rent/SqFt)"
        Else
            Range("Current_Rent").Value = "=IF(ISERROR(CurrentRentperSqFt*SqFt),"""",CurrentRentperSqFt*SqFt)"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing one of the cells with the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro. This triggers another event and the Worksheet_Change tries to run on top of itself with a new `Target`. You need to disable events so you can make the change(s) without triggering another event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("Current_Rent").Address Or Target.Address = Range("CurrentRentperSqFt").Address Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Address = Range("Current_Rent").Address Then
            Target.Formula = "=IFERROR(CurrentRentperSqFt*SqFt,"""")"
        Else
            Target.Formula = "=IFERROR(Current_Rent/SqFt,"""")"
        End If

    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've also modified your formulas to use the newer [IFERROR¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) that avoids the repetition of running the equation to check for an error before running it again to produce a result.

---

¹ <sub>The [IFERROR¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) was introduced with Excel 2007. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out and it worked. I appreciate your help!